# How to appendChild to every list item?

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I don't understand why can't I append upBtn to all the list items.
Thanks for any help you could provide.

```
// append upBtn to all exist lis
const upBtn = document.createElement("button");  
upBtn.className ="up";  
upBtn.textContent = "up";  
const lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");  
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {  
    lis[i].appendChild(upBtn);  
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild  Appending an existing node will move it, you need to create a new button for each append or clone it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to append the same button over and over again. You need to create a separate button each time.

Try this:

```
// append upBtn to all exist lis
const lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");  
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {  
    const upBtn = document.createElement("button");  
    upBtn.className ="up";  
    upBtn.textContent = "up";  
    lis[i].appendChild(upBtn);  
}
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ceseyadoho/edit?html,js,output